# contact form in template with jquery,validate and ajax

Tags: functions, theme-development, ajax, validation, contact

I have a page-contact.php for my contact form in my template. I wanted to add jquery validation and some fancy ajax action to my form. This is already a working code in a simple PHP page, but getting it work in wordpress fails.

My contact form:

```
<form id="contact_form" method="POST" action="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" id="name" placeholder="Your name">
    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" id="email" placeholder="Your email">
    <textarea rows="2" cols="40" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" size="15" placeholder="Please do not fill your phone number">
    <input type="submit" id="click" class="button" value="Submit">
    <div id="loading_icon"><img src="/wp-content/themes/owlish/img/loading.gif" alt="loading"></div>
    <div id="response"></div>
</form>
```

the ajax function in functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_sendmail', 'sendmail');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sendmail', 'sendmail');
    function sendmail() {
        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
            echo 'ajax success';
        } else {
            echo "<p class='error'>nothing submitted</p>";
        }
    die();
    }
```

And my javascript action:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contact_form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please enter your name",
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email adress",
                email: "Please enter your valid email adress"
            },
            message: "Please enter a short message, what your inquiry is about"
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#loading_icon').show();
            $('#click').hide();
            var params = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
                data: params,
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#response').hide();
                    $('#response').html(response);
                    $('#response').fadeIn('slow');
                    $('#loading_icon').hide();                      
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

The needed files are loaded correctly (/1.10.1/jquery.min.js, jquery.validate.js) but, this code keeps returning 0 despite the fact that I have `wp_ajax_nopriv_sendmail` in functions.php. The console does not return any error. I believe that I am missing some wp-specific fact, but which?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code doesn't use the sendmail action callback you defined. Additionally `0` is returned in case a action callback isn't found.

Comment: Oh can you clarify a little bit? Do you mean in js or functions? I tested with the function just echoing 'function fired' (I also implemented the change from the answer below)

Comment: You need to add the `action` param for your AJAX hook to fire: `data: params + "&action=sendmail",`

Comment: @TheDeadMedic THX so much! Now I see the response from the function!! I unfortunatedly cannot upvote, but its sure worth it

Comment: I see @TheDeadMedic did the clarification, I kind of thought what I was saying is clear, wrong assumption I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress is running Jquery in noconflict mode. [(WordPress Codex Reference)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)
 or read this brief article I posted some time ago. [View it here](http://mattroyal.co.za/2013/07/working-with-jquery-in-wordpress/).

You need to replace:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

With this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

So all together, try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#contact_form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please enter your name",
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email adress",
                email: "Please enter your valid email adress"
            },
            message: "Please enter a short message, what your inquiry is about"
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#loading_icon').show();
            $('#click').hide();
            var params = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
                data: params + "&action=sendmail",
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#response').hide();
                    $('#response').html(response);
                    $('#response').fadeIn('slow');
                    $('#loading_icon').hide();                      
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Your first link doesn't address the Codex, like the text suggests. Fixed it, instead of just complaining. :)

Comment: My pleasure, it is supposed to be collaborative anyway.

Comment: Thanks I changed the line, but still the response is just 0 .. see also comment below the question, thank you so much! Eager to learn more

Comment: I also changed all $ in the code to jQuery like in your article, but still the same

Comment: Now its working, see comment from TheDeadMedic ... thanks so much, I would upvote if I could

Comment: I've added the solution by TheDeadMedic to your code, so the answer is complete. @Owl I guess, you can accept it now.

Answer (score 0):

The line bellow probably does not read your action correctly that is why it returns 0

```
url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
data: params + "&action=sendmail",
```

Consider making an AJAX request similar to this:

```
// the value of 'action' is the key that will be identified by the 'wp_ajax_' hook 
var data = {
    'action': 'my_action',
    'message': 123
};

var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    // Output the response which should be 'Hellow World'
    alert(response);
});
```

Then in your callback:

```
// Check if set and if the received value is 123
if (isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message'] == 123 ) {
    echo 'Hello World';
}
// Always exit to avoid further execution
exit();
```

I found a very simple tutorial that pretty much describes the proper way of implementing AJAX in your WordPress blog: [Implementing AJAX in WordPress](http://carlofontanos.com/implementing-ajax-in-wordpress/)

Comment: "I found a very simple tutorial" talking about a tutorial you wrote is very bad and looks like spam for SEO.

Comment: @cybmeta sometimes people (*gasp*) blog what they know about WordPress! It looks perfectly fine to me, on top of very nice answer here. :) Although I would appreciate more upfront disclosure than "I found" indeed.

Comment: Of course, I have no problem with people blogging or posting external links for reference or for more information; I do. But reading the question, the accepted answer and this one, I really think that the purpose was only insert the link. Just my opinion.